# What is user league

Tags: discussion, meta

Hello today my reputation Reached to 298. Now under my reputation in my profile top 15% this quarter is written. When I click on this link it takes me on other page where it was written in front of my name.

```
#5382 quarter Rank +22319 change 277 quarter reputation
```

Can any one guide me what is this. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user leagues show you how your rep compares to others over a bunch of different time frames; it's showing the current quarter (the first three months of 2011) because the link you clicked from your profile said "this quarter" (it chooses whichever bracket you're highest in -- you're in the top 15% of all users based on your quarter reputation), but you can switch to week/month/year/all time views using the buttons at the top.

The different columns mean:

- **#5382 quarter rank** -- You have the 5382<sup>th</sup> highest rep this quarter
- **+22319 change** -- You've gone up 22319 places this quarter, so last quarter you were ranked 5382+22319 = #27701 quarter rank
- **277 quarter reputation** -- The amount of rep you've earned this quarter

Comment: A Comprehensive Answer.

Answer (score 1):

It just means that 277 reputation makes you fall under the top 15% of the all users for this quarter to end in March. This is a new feature on the profile that got recently added.